# Problem in a function that extracts and saves fields from a database table to another

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, function, tkinter

If in the combo_Nations combobox I select a specific Country (the country name is extracted from the "All_Nations" table in the "Nations_name" column), I would like to get the corresponding ID_Nations of the respective selected country (ID_Nations is found in the same table "All_Nations"). The ID will be automatically inserted in another table of the database together with other fields, after clicking on the "Add" button with the function def_add.
(If you are wondering why I need to automatically insert the ID_Nation from another table, the reason is that I need it for relational purposes for a Foreign Key)

So I would like to take this data circled in red from the screenshot (I cannot attach images here): [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhXal.png). Basically the table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE "All_Nations" (
    "ID_Nations"    INTEGER, >>> example: 453
    "Nations_name"  INTEGER, >>> example: England
    PRIMARY KEY("ID_Nations" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

So the combobox combo_Nations with the def combo_nations function fetches Nations_name only. While def id_nations should extract ID_Nations corresponding to the selected Nation from the combobox. **EXAMPLE:** For example, if I select England in the combobox, id_nations should automatically save me 453. The two data will be saved in a new table thanks to the function def add () (I only wrote part of this code so as not to dwell on it, showing you the minimum to understand what I serves, because it works correctly). The new table will save a row in which there will be: ID, Nations_name, ID_Nations, other data of various kinds.

The error I get is this TypeError: 'list' object is not callable, to be precise this is it:

```
   db.insert(nations.get(),.....other data .get(), id_campionati_value())
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I don't know if I wrote the def id_nations function incorrectly, if the problem is in db.insert or if the problem is both

**HERE'S THE CODE.** There is some problem in the def id_nations function I created:

```
def id_nations():
    nations = combo_Nations.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT ID_Nations FROM All_Nations WHERE Nations_name=?',(nations,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    return result

#this is ok. no problem
def combo_nations():
    campionato = combo_Nations.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT Nations_name FROM All_Nations')
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result

#Combobox Nations
lbl_Nations = Label(root, text="Nations", font=("Calibri", 11), bg="#E95420", fg="white")
lbl_Nations.place(x=6, y=60)
combo_Nations = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Calibri", 11), width=30, textvariable=nations, state="readonly")
combo_Nations.place(x=180, y=60)
combo_Nations.set("Select")
combo_Nations['values'] = combo_nations()
combo_Nations.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_city)
```

The data will be saved here (everything works fine):

```
def add():
    id_campionati_value=id_campionati()
    
    db.insert(nations.get(),.....other data .get(), id_campionati_value())
    messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Record Inserted")
    clearAll()
    dispalyAll()
```

Theoretically I understand what the problem is, but I don't know how to solve it. I'm just starting out with Python. Can you show me the solution in the answer? Thanks

P.S: I removed unnecessary parts of code so as not to lengthen the question, but there is everything you need to understand. Thanks

**UPDATE
Rest of the code to insert data into the database.** I write it in a somewhat confusing way because I have two files (main.py and db.py) and the code is split. If I write all the code of the two files it is too long.

```
def getData(event):
    selected_row = tv.focus()
    data = tv.item(selected_row)
    global row
    row = data["values"]
    #print(row)

    nations.set(row[1])
    ....
    id_nations.set(row[10])



    # Insert Function
    def insert(self, nations,....., id_nations):
        self.cur.execute("insert into All_Nations values (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                         (nations,..., id_nations))
        self.con.commit()
```

Comment: from the given info it seems that you did sth like this: `lst = []; lst()` which obviously will raise that error, you should provide a [mre] and the full error traceback

Comment: @Matiiss I thank you for the answer. The code is very long and a bit confusing, difficult to give an example. I can add more details in the question. If you re-read the question, I have written a few more things. Hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: `id_campionati()` appears to return a list, meaning that you probably wan to do this: `db.insert(nations.get(),.....other data .get(), id_campionati_value)`, if that doesn't help then you will need to provide an actual [mre] and a complete error traceback (starting at word Traceback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error, `id_campionati_value` is a list. When you do `id_campionati_value()` you're calling the list, and as the error says, you can't call the list.

Since you seem to need a single value, you first need to define `id_nations` to return the id rather than a list. It would look something like in the following example, returning the first column of the matching row.

I would also suggest renaming the function to make it more clear that it's fetching something from the database:

```
def get_id_nations():
    nations = combo_Nations.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT ID_Nations FROM All_Nations WHERE Nations_name=?',(nations,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    return result[0]
```

Then, you can use this value when calling `db.insert`:

```
id_nations = get_id_nations()
db.insert(nations.get(),.....other data .get(), id_nations)
```

Comment: I don't want to have a list. I was wrong in writing the function. How can I modify the def id_nations function so that I do NOT have a list, but only the single ID I need?In this way with id_campionato_value I will not recall the first value with [0], but it will be recalled itself directly through the function.Can you show me how to change the function?Obviously I thank you with the solution of [0]: nice idea, but it is obvious that I was wrong to write the function. P.S: I updated the question with an "update", inserting, for information, the code for saving in the database

Comment: I add to the comment above (I don't know if you already read): could you show me how to change the id_nations function to not have a list but a single ID directly? Thanks

Comment: I noticed that you changed the comment to "return result [0]". Isn't there a way to modify my function id_nations with the purpose of NOT getting a list, but directly the single field I need? I don't want a list . Thanks

Comment: @CarryOnWaywardSon96: I don't know what you mean. I _did_ change the function to return a single result. `fetchone` returns a list, `result[0]` takes a single value from that list and returns it.

Comment: Ah ok, got it. With result = cursor.fetchone () your code doesn't work, while with result = [row [0] for row in cursor] it works correctly. Thanks for answering me and thanks for helping me. In a few minutes I will post a similar but different question. Could you help me please? Thanks

Comment: _"Ah ok, got it. With result = cursor.fetchone () your code doesn't work, while with result = [row [0] for row in cursor] it works correctly."_ - no, it shouldn't work in either case. Both of those return a list rather than a single value.

Comment: I just checked and it works fine with result = [row [0] for row in cursor] and then return result [0]. If I select a different country, a different ID is entered in the database which would exactly match the country. In the case of my example in the question, ID 453 is saved if I select England. Why do you say it shouldn't work and why does it work properly for me?

Comment: @CarryOnWaywardSon96: I misunderstood your earlier comment. However, `[row[0] for row in cursor]` should return essentially the same thing as `cursor.fetchone()`. One returns a list, one returns a tuple, but both the list and tuple have the same data.